# Tailwind: having equal width columns without repeating something like w-full in every column

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I'm trying to make sense of the simplest way to create responsive equal-width columns with Tailwind, but ideally without having to repeat the same class on every column.

This works:

```html
<div class="container mx-auto p-10">
  <div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row gap-8">
    <div class="md:flex-1 h-[100px] bg-gray-300" />
    <div class="md:flex-1 h-[100px] bg-gray-400" />
    <div class="md:flex-1 h-[100px] bg-gray-500" />
  </div>
</div>
```

As does this:

```html
<div class="container mx-auto p-10">
  <div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row gap-8">
    <div class="w-full h-[100px] bg-gray-300" />
    <div class="w-full h-[100px] bg-gray-400" />
    <div class="w-full h-[100px] bg-gray-500" />
  </div>
</div>
```

But is there no simpler way than having to repeat `md:flex-1` or `w-full` inside every column? Basically my question is how to make this behavior the default for all columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give the parent element a class name like `parent`

```html
<div class="container mx-auto p-10">
  <div class="parent flex flex-col md:flex-row gap-8">
    <div class="bg-gray-300" />
    <div class="bg-gray-400" />
    <div class="bg-gray-500" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Then in the CSS file try this:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

.parent div{
  @apply w-40 md:flex-1 h-[100px];
}
```